# Get custom attribute from SubClass in BaseClass (C# .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, custom-attributes

Ok, edited the code for clarification:

Question: How can I access the attribute `[MyAttr("...")]` in `TestClassOne/Two` from `BaseClass.TheAttribute`...?

All classes except TestClassOne/Two will be compiled in to my "core" and delivered as a dev-platform to a customer.
The TestClassOne/Two is developed by the customer, so there can be no knowledge of the TestClassOne/Two in the "core".

Code below is compiled into "core" and delivered to customer as dll.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void AttrTest()
{
    var one = new TestClassOne();
    var attrOne = one.MyTestProperty.TheAttribute;

    var two = new TestClassTwo();
    var attrTwo = two.MyTestProperty.TheAttribute;
}

public class MyAttr : Attribute
{
    private string _test;
    public MyAttr(string test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string TheAttribute
    {
        get { 
            // Here I would like to get the "[MyAttr("...")]" from the classes in the bottom

            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

Code below is developed by customer (using my dll's)

```
public class TestClassOne
{
    [MyAttr("Attribute one")]
    public SubClass MyTestProperty = new SubClass();
}

public class TestClassTwo
{
    [MyAttr("Attribute two")]
    public SubClass MyTestProperty = new SubClass();
}
```

Comment: I have ask another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569139/how-to-get-which-type-of-parent-object-to-reference-the-current-object-via-prope. If this question is answered, your questions will be surely answered

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 3:**

You can walk the call stack, looking for a relevant attribute in a relevant member in a relevant class. Try this:

```
public class MyAttr : Attribute
{
    private string _test;
    public MyAttr(string test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }

    public string getAttr()
    {
        return _test;
    }
}


public class BaseClass
{
    private string theString;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        StackTrace callStack = new StackTrace();

        for ( int i = 0; i < callStack.FrameCount; i++ )
        {
            Type t = callStack.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
            foreach ( MemberInfo m in t.GetMembers().Where(x => typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(x.Type)) )
            {
                foreach ( var z in  m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttr)) )
                {
                    MyAttr theAttr = z as MyAttr;
                    if ( z!= null )
                    {
                        theString = z.getAttr();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string Test
    {
        get { 
            return theString;
        }
    }
}
```

This requires that your customer always initializes the SubClass member inside the class that declares it. If they start deriving `TestClassOne` or have it and `TestClassTwo` derive from a common class that initializes the member, this code will break.

With clever use of reflection, you can expand the above code to cover more use cases, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

**Edit 2:**

No. I'm sorry, but what you're trying to do isn't possible. There's no "normal" way for an instance of `SubClass` to know if it's being declared in a member field of some other object, or in an element in an array or in a temporary variable in the stack, or whatever. As such, there's no way for that instance to access the attributes of the member field that's declaring it.

(I suppose you might want to try to access the garbage collector to find out where in memory the `this` object lives, but that's probably way beyond the scope of this problem, and in any case, not something I know how to do.)

I suspect your problem lies elsewhere entirely. Maybe you need to require your customer to make `TestClassOne` and `TestClassTwo` derive from a common abstract class. Maybe they need to derive from `BaseClass` themselves. Maybe you need to add parameters to the constructor. Maybe you need to provide a different interface altogether. We can't know unless you provide more information on your specific business requirements.

**Edit:**

To access the attributes declared on the MyTest member, try something along these lines:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Test
    {
        get { 
            var attr = typeof(Test).GetMembers().Where(x => x.Type == this.GetType()).First().GetCustomAttributes(true);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This will search class `Test` for a member with the same type as `this` and look for attributes on that member.

(I don't have my Visual Studio here, to check the exact `Where` syntax, but it should be pretty close to that...)

**Original Answer:**

Your attribute is declared on the `MyTest` member of class `Test`. But, you're doing `GetCustomAttributes` on class `SubClass` itself.

Try this:

```
[MyAttr("apa")]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{

}

public class Test
{
    public SubClass MyTest = new SubClass();
}
```

Should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately the attribute must be declared in the Test class. Is there a way to access the attributes declared on the "MyTest" member in the Test class?

Comment: Thanks again, but this requires knowledge of the type "Test" within BaseClass. The thought is that everything but "Test" should be precompiled and that I can create several more classes like "Test" and that my BaseClass can work with them all.

Comment: @MattiasRundqvist: how input of Test class look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...?
All classes except TestClassOne/Two will be compiled in to my "core" and delivered as a dev-platform to a customer.
The TestClassOne/Two is developed by the customer, so there can be no knowledge of the TestClassOne/Two in the "core".

Comment: You keep changing the requirements. What you want to do isn't possible. I'll make a note in an edit.

Comment: Not a problem. Your issue is an interesting one. I look forward to hearing more about it, so I can be more helpful. :)

Comment: I just thought of something you can do! You can walk the stack trace in `BaseClass`'s constructor, looking for a relevant method in a relevant class. I'll experiment with the syntax, then get back to you.

Comment: Edit is up. I put it at the top, this time, to make it easier to find. Let me know if that one works for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can get directly from type `Test`:

```
var result = typeof (Test)
               .GetField("MyTest", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .GetCustomAttribute<MyAttr>();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this wont work in my case. This requires knowledge of the type "Test" within BaseClass. The thought is that everything but "Test" should be precompiled and that I can create several more classes like "Test" and that my BaseClass can work with them all.

Comment: @MattiasRundqvist: You should edit your question to show clearer sample

Comment: Edited the code. Hope I managed to make my problem more clear now.